# Resolving gradle owned projects dependencies

Tags: java, gradle

Project structure:

```
root
-- 0. CAN'T add multi-project here
----\ a. ProjectCommonUtil
----\ b. ProjectWeb
----\ c. ProjectBatchUtil
----\ d. ProjectHttpClientUtil
----\ e. ProjectBatchWithMainClass
----\ lib
```

Dependencies:

1. ProjectCommonUtil -> none
2. ProjectWeb -> a, c, d
3. ProjectBatchUtil -> none
4. ProjectHttpClientUtil -> a
5. ProjectBatchWithMainClass -> b, c, d(a)

Without worrying about open source dependencies yet, here is what I am struggling with:

1. Ability to build each project separately

   1. Dependencies should be determined in lib folder jars

      1. If dependency jar is missing, build dependency and cc: jar to lib folder

         Ex: d depends on a. a's jar is not in lib folder so build a then place in lib folder, then build d

         These are the included `build.gradle` files I have provided below
2. The lib folder in the above structure contains

   1. Jars of a,b (yes, in jar form b/c of e), c, d, e
   2. An Ear file of b. ProjectWeb, containing jars a, c, d in the appropriate WEB-INF/lib folder in b. ProjectWeb

I cannot create a gradle multi-project in between root and the existing projects and I cannot create fat jars.  Maybe I'm trying to micromanage gradle but this #2 is what I need because I need to deploy the web ear to an app server and the batch (e.) and it's dependencies to several linux VMs in multiple locations running variations of e. with different JVM args.

Help!

TIA,
Bill

a. ProjectCommonUtil build.gradle

```
/*
 * This build file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task.
 *
 * This generated file contains a commented-out sample Java project to get you started.
 * For more details take a look at the Java Quickstart chapter in the Gradle
 * user guide available at https://docs.gradle.org/4.3/userguide/tutorial_java_projects.html
 */

// +++++++++++++++++++++ ORDER IS IMPORTANT ++++++++++++++++
plugins {
    id 'base'
}


// Apply the java plugin to add support for Java
apply plugin: 'java'
//apply plugin: 'checkstyle'
apply plugin: 'jdepend'
apply plugin: 'pmd'
apply plugin: 'project-report'

build.dependsOn('copyArcCommonProjectJar', 'copyArcCommonExternalJars')
group "com.mmm.arc"
version =  '2.5.ArcCommon'

// In this section you declare where to find the dependencies of your project
repositories {
    // Use 'jcenter' for resolving your dependencies.
    // You can declare any Maven/Ivy/file repository here.
    jcenter()
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8   

sourceSets {
    main {
         java {
              srcDir 'src'
              }
         }
}

// Short hand form
//compileJava.doFirst { println 'In compileJava:BEGIN' }
//compileJava.doLast { println 'In compileJava:END' }

tasks.create(name: 'copyArcCommonProjectJar', type: Copy, dependsOn: 'jar') {
    into "../CommonJars/ArcProjectJars"
        from "${buildDir}/libs"
        include "*.jar"
}   
copyArcCommonProjectJar.doFirst { 
  println "${buildDir}:In copyArcCommonProjectJar:BEGIN" 

  // Remove existing jars only if build is necessary
  delete "../CommonJars/ArcProjectJars/${name}*.jar"
}
copyArcCommonProjectJar.doLast { println 'In copyArcCommonProjectJar:END' }
//copyArcCommon.outputs.upToDateWhen { false }

tasks.create(name: 'copyArcCommonExternalJars', type: Copy, dependsOn: 'dependencies') {
    into "../CommonJars"
      from configurations.runtime
    //include "*.jar"
} 
copyArcCommonExternalJars.doFirst { println 'In copyArcCommonExternalJars:BEGIN' }
copyArcCommonExternalJars.doLast { println 'In copyArcCommonExternalJars:END' }
//copyExternalJars.outputs.upToDateWhen { false }

jar {
    //baseName = 'ArcCommon'
}
jar.doFirst { println 'In jar:BEGIN' }
jar.doLast { println 'In jar:END' }
//jar.outputs.upToDateWhen { false }


// In this section you declare the dependencies for your production and test code
dependencies {
    // The production code uses the SLF4J logging API at implementation time
    // implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25'
    // implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:+'

    // Declare the dependency for your favourite test framework you want to use in your tests.
    // TestNG is also supported by the Gradle Test task. Just change the
    // testimplementation dependency to testimplementation 'org.testng:testng:6.8.1' and add
    // 'test.useTestNG()' to your build script.
//    testimplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    // providedimplementation is for jars need to build but are provided at runtime
    // providedimplementation 
}
```

d. ProjectHttpClientUtil build.gradle

```
/*
 * This build file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task.
 *
 * This generated file contains a commented-out sample Java project to get you started.
 * For more details take a look at the Java Quickstart chapter in the Gradle
 * user guide available at https://docs.gradle.org/4.3/userguide/tutorial_java_projects.html
 */

// +++++++++++++++++++++ ORDER IS IMPORTANT ++++++++++++++++
plugins {
    id 'base'
}


// Apply the java plugin to add support for Java
apply plugin: 'java'
//apply plugin: 'checkstyle'
apply plugin: 'jdepend'
apply plugin: 'pmd'
apply plugin: 'project-report'

build.dependsOn(
    'buildArcCommon',
    'copyArcProjectJar', 'copyExternalJars'
)
group "com.mmm.arc"
version =  '2.5.TekExHTTPClient'

// In this section you declare where to find the dependencies of your project
repositories {
    // Use 'jcenter' for resolving your dependencies.
    // You can declare any Maven/Ivy/file repository here.
    jcenter()
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8   

sourceSets {
    main {
         java {
              srcDir 'src'
              }
         }
}

task buildArcCommon(type: GradleBuild) {
    doFirst {
       println '---  Compiling ArcCommon ---'
        buildFile = '../ArcCommon/build.gradle/'
    }
   // tasks = ['build']
}

tasks.create(name: 'copyArcProjectJar', type: Copy, dependsOn: 'jar') {
    into "../CommonJars/ArcProjectJars"
        from "${buildDir}/libs"
        include "*.jar"
}   
copyArcProjectJar.doFirst { 
  println 'In copyArcCommon:BEGIN' 

  // Remove existing jars only if build is necessary
  delete "../CommonJars/ArcProjectJars/${name}*.jar"
}
copyArcProjectJar.doLast { println 'In copyArcCommon:END' }
//copyArcCommon.outputs.upToDateWhen { false }

tasks.create(name: 'copyExternalJars', type: Copy, dependsOn: 'dependencies') {
    into "../CommonJars"
      from configurations.runtime
    //include "*.jar"
} 
copyExternalJars.doFirst { println 'In copyExternalJars:BEGIN' }
copyExternalJars.doLast { println 'In copyExternalJars:END' }
//copyExternalJars.outputs.upToDateWhen { false }

//See above short hand
/*
task myTask (  ) {
   println '+++++++++++++  Compiling ArcCommon BEGIN  ++++++++++++++++'
}
*/

// Short hand form
/*
implementationJava.doFirst { 
    println '+++++++++++++  Compiling TekExHTTPClient BEGIN  ++++++++++++++++'
//  tasks = [ "buildArcCommon", "taskCopyAllTekExProjects" ]
//  dependsOn buildArcCommon, taskCopyAllTekExProjects
}

implementationJava.doLast { println '+++++++++++++  Compiling TekExHTTPClient END  ++++++++++++++++'}

//implementationJava.myTask



task taskCopyAllTekExProjects(type: Copy) {
    into 'build/libs'
    include '../ArcCommon/build/libs/*.jar'
}

//taskCopyAllTekExProjects.mustRunAfter 'buildArcCommon'

/*
task test(dependsOn: [implementation, implementationTest]) {
    doLast {
        println '+++++++++++++  Running ArcCommon Unit Tests  ++++++++++++++++'
    }
}
*/
/*
task dist(dependsOn: [implementation, test]) {
    doLast {
        println '+++++++++++++  Building ArcCommon Jar  ++++++++++++++++'

    }
}
*/

jar {
   // baseName = 'TekExHTTPClient'
}

// In this section you declare the dependencies for your production and test code
dependencies {
    // The production code uses the SLF4J logging API at implementation time
    implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:+'
    implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:+'
    compile fileTree (dir: '../CommonJars/ArcProjectJars')

    // Declare the dependency for your favourite test framework you want to use in your tests.
    // TestNG is also supported by the Gradle Test task. Just change the
    // testimplementation dependency to testimplementation 'org.testng:testng:6.8.1' and add
    // 'test.useTestNG()' to your build script.
//    testimplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    // providedimplementation is for jars need to build but are provided at runtime
    // providedimplementation 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are definitely fighting Gradle and having to compensate for things it will handle for you if you amend your setup a bit.

The multi project definition can perfectly live at the same level as the projects it aggregates. Simply add a new directory with a `build.gradle` and a `settings.gradle`, and reference the different modules you need to integrate:

```
    includeFlat 'a'
    includeFlat 'b'
    includeFlat 'c'
    includeFlat 'd'
    includeFlat 'e'
```

and then you can express dependencies between the projects, add packaging tasks that do the necessary copies to the lib folder, etc ...

Comment: Thank you @Louis .  When I do as you suggest and just do 'a', I am now encountering "Could not normalize path for file" because of the "..". This did not occur previously. Any ideas (not finding much help using google)?

Comment: I have fixed my example, what I suggested was wrong. `includeFlat` is your friend there - https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.initialization.Settings.html#org.gradle.api.initialization.Settings:includeFlat(java.lang.String[])

Answer (score 0):

includeFlat may be another option as Louis suggests.  This is how I solved my issue.

`ArcGradle
   ProjectCommon
   lib\ArcProjectJars`

ArcGradle settings.gradle
`rootProject.name = 'ArcGradle'
    include ':ProjectCommon'
    project(':ProjectCommon').projectDir = file('../ProjectCommon')`

ArcGradle build.gradle

```
subprojects {
    // +++++++++++++++++++++ ORDER IS IMPORTANT ++++++++++++++++
    apply plugin: 'java'
    group "com.mmm.arc"
    version =  '2.5.0'
    sourceCompatibility = 1.8
    targetCompatibility = 1.8
    build.dependsOn('copyProjectJar')
    clean.dependsOn('deleteProjectJar')

    // In this section you declare where to find the dependencies of your project
    repositories {
        // Use 'jcenter' for resolving your dependencies.
        // You can declare any Maven/Ivy/file repository here.
        jcenter()
    }

    ext {
        arcProjectJarDir = "${rootDir}${File.separator}CommonJars${File.separator}ArcProjectJars"
    } 

    tasks.create(name: 'copyProjectJar', type: Copy) {
        into "${arcProjectJarDir}"
            from "/build/libs"
            include "*.jar"
    }   
    copyProjectJar.doFirst { 
        println "${project.name}:In copyProjectJar:BEGIN" 
    }
    copyProjectJar.doLast { println 'In copyProjectJar:END' }
    copyProjectJar.dependsOn('jar','deleteProjectJar')
    tasks.create(name: 'deleteProjectJar', type:Delete) {
        // Remove existing jars only if build is necessary
        delete fileTree(dir: "${arcProjectJarDir}", include: "${project.name}*.jar")
    }
}
```

And my ArcCommon settings.gradle is empty and the build.gradle only contains dependencies{}

I could add `rootProject.name = 'ArcCommon'` to settings.gradle but it's inferred from the folder name